# nginx and wordpress different docker-compose files

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am trying to connect multiple docker-compose files with one nginx docker-compose file.

For example, this setup works great(I've create the network before running):

*(Bear with me here. I know this example is redundant because I have two nginx servers)*

```
#static_site/docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: app_web_static
    volumes:
      - "./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
      - "./web:/var/www/static_web"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - test_network
```

---

```
#static_site/nginx.conf
server {
    listen 8080;

    location / {
       root /var/www/static_web;
       index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

---

```
#nginx/docker-compose.yml
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.local;

    #Docker DNS
    resolver 127.0.0.11;

    location / {
        set $docker_host "app_web_static"; 
        proxy_pass http://$docker_host:8080;
    }
}
```

I run the containers and everything works as expected. My website is proxied over myapp.local

BUT. When I change my static website to a wordpress image like this:

```
#wordpress/docker-composer.yml
wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    container_name: app_web
    links:
      - db:mysql
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: example
    networks:
      - test_network
      - test_wordpress_db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: test.web.db
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - test_wordpress_db
```

I run the containers again(after updating the nginx .yml file). I get the request logged in my terminal (nginx container which means the request is handle) but as an error :
`test.nginx | [error] 5#5: *6 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.23.0.1, server: myapp.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.23.0.2:8080/", host: "myapp.local"`

The thing is that the wordpress app is working when I access it from `localhost:8080`.

Is there a problem with the wordpress app in this configuration? It cannot detect my host or something? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

It seems I have to use the internal port for my proxy_pass not the external one. For example, for the wordpress `docker-compose.yml` file I have to write the proxy like so:

```
#nginx/docker-compose.yml
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.local;

    #Docker DNS
    resolver 127.0.0.11;

    location / {
        set $docker_host "app_web_static"; 
        proxy_pass http://$docker_host:80; # here. the internal wordpress port
    }
}
```